# Appending labels to a div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-objects

I have an empty div ,

```
<div id="display">
</div>
```

And I have a list where I have names to be displayed as labels in this empty div.How to display the list dynamically as a thumbnail in the empty div using jquery?

Comment: show what you have tried so far

Comment: how is your list stored?

Comment: The list is stored as an  array , where it has 10 elements with name and id in each element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how your list is stored. Is it in a basic array?

you can append to the Div like:

```
$('#display').append('<label>Some Text</label>');
```

if you have an array of things:

```
myArray = array('a','b','c');

$.each(myArray, function(k,v){
    $('#display').append('<label>'+v+'</label>');
});
```

Comment: Actually , the list is a complicated data structure , where one main object contains a list of arrays and inside one more list . Thanks for the idea

Comment: You mean it is multidimensional.. You can handle that by iterating through each subset using the each method again.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "Friday", "saturday", "Sunday"];
```

using jquery **each** and **Append** function you can add dynamic contents to the div.

```
$(list).each ( function (i,elem) {  
$('#display').append ('<div style="border:1px solid red; height:100px; width:100px; float:left" > ' + elem+ ' </div>')});
```